# Liquid template Minus operation

Tags: liquid, azure-logic-apps, dotliquid

I'm trying to substract 2 variables from 2 strings in source json. Even with a math filter to convert them to number/float, I'm getting :

**Liquid error: Parameter count mismatch.**

{% assign my_v1="12.24" | plus: 1  %}

{% assign my_v2="10.24" | plus: 1 %}

{{ my_v1 | Minus : my_v2}}

expected value : 2.24

any help please?

Comment: Same discussion on Q&A : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/547579/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liquid action follows the DotLiquid implementation for Liquid as mentioned here. Looks like the [issue](https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid/issues/404) that you have observed was fixed recently [here](https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid/pull/420).

Currently logic app supports 2.0.361 version of DotLiquid. The product team will be updating it to the latest version and we will update the version information in our document. The current ETA for this change is March 2022 but could be changed due to unforeseen circumstances.